# imageloader error in place of url[position]

Tags: android, json

I am using imageloader to load thumbnail images from json response, there are lots of images obtained from json response need to parse that and place images in listview. I am getting confuse what to add in place of `url[position]` getting error in  `imgLoader.DisplayImage(url[position], loader, image);` any one help me to find solution it would be a great help for me and your answer will be appreciated. thank you in advance.

following is the code and json response:

```
   public class AndroidLoadImageFromURLActivity extends ListActivity {

    // url to make request
   private static String desi = "http://website";

   // JSON Node names
   private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
   private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
   private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
   private static final String TAG_DATE = "date";
   private static final String TAG_CONTENT = "content";
   private static final String TAG_AUTHOR = "author";
   private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
   private static final String TAG_ATTACHMENTS = "attachments";
   private static final String TAG_IMAGES = "images";
   private static final String TAG_THUMBNAIL = "thumbnail";
   private static final String TAG_URL = "url";

   // contacts JSONArray
   JSONArray posts = null;


      @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.list_item);

        // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

     // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(desi);

    try {
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        posts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

        // looping through All Contacts
        for(int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
            String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
            String content = c.getString(TAG_CONTENT);
            // to remove all <P> </p> and <br /> and replace with ""
             content = content.replace("<br />", "");
             content = content.replace("<p>", "");
             content = content.replace("</p>", "");

            // Author is agin  JSON Object
            JSONObject author = c.getJSONObject(TAG_AUTHOR);
            String name = author.getString(TAG_NAME);

            JSONArray attachments = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ATTACHMENTS);

            for(int j = 0; j < attachments.length(); j++){
                JSONObject d = attachments.getJSONObject(i);


            JSONObject thumbnail = d.getJSONObject(TAG_THUMBNAIL);
            String url = thumbnail.getString(TAG_URL);
            }

            // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();



            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_ID, id);
            map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
            map.put( TAG_DATE, date);
            map.put( TAG_NAME, name);
            map.put( TAG_CONTENT, content);
            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            contactList.add(map);
        }   
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
            R.layout.list_row,
            new String[] { TAG_TITLE, TAG_DATE, TAG_NAME, TAG_CONTENT, TAG_URL },
        new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.email,R.id.mobile, R.id.content, R.id.list_image});

    setListAdapter(adapter);

          // Loader image - will be shown before loading image
           int loader = R.drawable.loader;

             // Imageview to show
          ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.list_image);


    // ImageLoader class instance
     ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());


    // whenever you want to load an image from url
    // call DisplayImage function
    // url - image url to load
    // loader - loader image, will be displayed before getting image
    // image - ImageView 
    imgLoader.DisplayImage(url[position], loader, image);
    }
     }
```

JSON response

```
{
"status": "ok",

"posts": [
    {
        "id": 2498,
        "title": "jigsaw lamp imported from thailand",
        "content": "<p>Hi. It&#8217;s a invitation to have a look at a unique lamp shade called jigsaw lamp from thailand. Available in multi attractive colours.</p>\n",
        "date": "2012-12-26 09:48:15",
         "author": {
            "name": "Tapas123456",
                        },
            "attachments": [
            {
                "description": "",
                "caption": "",
                "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
                "images": {

                    "thumbnail": {
                        "url": "http://site/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/646675-50x47.jpg",

                    }
                }
            },...............
```

logcat error

```
12-26 16:53:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(330): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 16:53:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(330): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.imagefromurl/com.androidhive.imagefromurl.AndroidLoadImageFromURLActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
12-26 16:53:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
12-26 16:53:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-26 16:53:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-26 16:53:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-26 16:53:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-26 16:53:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-26 16:53:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-26 16:53:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 16:53:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-26 16:53:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-26 16:53:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-26 16:53:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-26 16:53:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(330): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
12-26 16:53:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:245)
12-26 16:53:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:201)
12-26 16:53:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
12-26 16:53:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.androidhive.imagefromurl.AndroidLoadImageFromURLActivity.onCreate(AndroidLoadImageFromURLActivity.java:44)
12-26 16:53:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-26 16:53:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

Comment: which error ? show your logcat trace

Comment: compiler error url cannot be resolved to a variable@CapDroid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared **url** variable as **String** inside for loop

below is your code..

```
for(int j = 0; j < attachments.length(); j++)
{
JSONObject d = attachments.getJSONObject(i);
JSONObject thumbnail = d.getJSONObject(TAG_THUMBNAIL);
String url = thumbnail.getString(TAG_URL);
}
```

just need to declare url as `url` as global

like below code.

```
String url;
for(int j = 0; j < attachments.length(); j++)
    {
    JSONObject d = attachments.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject thumbnail = d.getJSONObject(TAG_THUMBNAIL);
    url = thumbnail.getString(TAG_URL);
    }
```

and use that `url`

```
imgLoader.DisplayImage(url, loader, image);
```